# div over mpg video

Tags: css, video

I am trying to position a transparent button over an embeded mpeg video?

I can position the buttons, but when the page loads, it seems the buttons are behind the 
movie.

This works in Mac Safari and Firefox, but not in IE or PC Firefox.

I've tried z-index but I'm sure I'm not doing it right. The link is http://www.ba-doyn.com/junk/video/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `wmode="transparent"` to your `embed` tag:

```
<div id="video">
    <embed src="final_hsbvideo_12-8.mpg" width="480" height="375" wmode="transparent"></embed>
    <div id="button1">button1</div>
    <div id="button2">button2</div>     
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yrecK/

Comment: That did it. Thanks so much. I thought that wmode was only for Flash video.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try giving the video embed a z-index lower than 100?

Comment: I believe I did, but when trying many permutations I might have missed it. I'll try and give it a z-inex of 1.